# ¿Como obtener un id desde una url para una api?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy enviando un correo con el id de una solicitud que estoy creado con net core MVC.
En mi botón de `Ir a solicitud` coloca la url a donde debe de ir, que es la que se muestra en las imágenes de abajo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que no puedo cachar el `idSolicitud`, me llega en 0 el parámetro para obtener la información.

Esta es mi función de JS cuando entro al controlador de `Vacaciones/EditarSolicitud?idSolicitud=15`

```
function GetDaysCalendar() {

        $.get('/Vacaciones/ObtenerDiasAprobados/idSolicitud=')
            .done(function (data) {

                var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
                var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
               
            });

    }
```

Este es mi método:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult ObtenerDiasAprobados([FromRoute]int idSolicitud)
    {
        List<VacacionesDiasAprobadosM> listDias = calendarioR.ObtenerDiasAprobados(idSolicitud);
        return Json(listDias);
    }
```

Estuve intentando colocarle `[FromRoute]` pero no lo logré, espero me puedan guiar a ver mi error.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes obtener la URL usando [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Ejemplo

```
function GetDaysCalendar() {
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  $.get('/Vacaciones/ObtenerDiasAprobados/idSolicitud=' + urlParams.get('idSolicitud'))
  .done(function (data) {
    let Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
    let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**[FromRoute]** es para parámetros antes del "?" por ejemplo en rutas como `'/Vacaciones/{id}/ObtenerDiasAprobados?idSolicitud=15'` (Route Parameters de una URI)

**[FromQuery]** es para parámetros después del "?", que es el que tienes que usar (Query Parameters de una URI)

en caso de que no te funcione puedes probar **[FromUri]** que funciona igual que el [FromQuery] en ASP.NET Core MVC API

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en tu función `GetDaysCalendar()` que no recibe ningún parametro, en el caso que quieres enviar un **Id** tu código puede quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
function GetDaysCalendar(idSolicitud) {

        $.get('/Vacaciones/ObtenerDiasAprobados/' + idSolicitud)
            .done(function (data) {

                var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
                var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
               
            });
    }
```

Aunque puedo notar que la URL que muestras en la imagen es diferente a la que agregaste de ejemplo siendo la de la imagen `/Vacaciones/EditarSolicitud`, pero para el caso de `GetDaysCalendar` así debería poder recibir el **Id** llamando la función dependiendo del contexto de tu código:

```
GetDaysCalendar(idSolicitud);
```